Is the Least Squares Estimate (LSE) the same as the Least Squares (LS) method, and why is the LSE the mean in the Rayleigh case?
I’m working on a problem related to the Rayleigh distribution, where I am asked to determine the ML estimate and the LS estimate of the parameter b. The assignment also asks me to derive a confidence interval for b, using the LS estimate. Here’s the exact problem statement.
I’ve managed to compute the LS estimate for b, but I’m confused about the terminology. Specifically:

Is it correct to say that the result of the least squares method is just the arithmetic mean of the input data? How does it in a Rayleigh case lead to an LS estimate that is the mean of the sample after some simplification?

Is the "LS estimate" (LSE) the same thing as the "LS method"? The assignment consistently refers to the LS estimate and never uses "LS method," which makes me think there might be a difference. Shouldn’t the LS method just refer to the process of minimizing the sum of squared residuals?


There's a definition of the LS method

the result of the least-squares method is the arithmetic mean of the input data.

Which makes me think, ah, it makes sense then that $\hat{b}$ would be the mean in the confidence interval formula:
$$C I=\bar{x} \pm z \frac{s}{\sqrt{n}}$$
Then the LS estimate obtained from the previous exercise would make sense, you'd just plug in $\hat{b}$ that was obtained from the previous exercise, and put it in place of $\bar{x}$ to find the confidence interval. But it's still not clear if the LSE and LS Method is the same thing.
Any help or insights that could help me with this is greatly appreciated :)
